# NoMethodError in DocsController#new undefined method `docs' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am trying to follow a tutorial and build an app like evernote or google docs where a user can store files. I am trying to associate users with the docs and I want the current user to create a new doc and I want that doc to have the id of that user and I get this error when trying to create a new 
NoMethodError in DocsController#new
undefined method `docs' for nil:NilClass

Extracted source (around line #13):
11
12
13
14
15
16

```
def new
    @doc = current_user.docs.build
end

def create
```

Rails.root: /Users/Hisham/Desktop/Rails_projects/cabinet

Application Trace | Framework Trace | Full Trace
app/controllers/docs_controller.rb:13:in `new'

Comment: Could you rephrase this as a question? It's unclear what you're looking for help with.

Also, do you have the link to the tutorial? This would be helpful extra information.

Comment: And so? Where is `current_user` implementation?

Comment: `@doc = current_user.docs.build if current_user.present? `

Comment: Make sure you are logged in or you will get `nil` value in `current_user`

Comment: ```current_user``` is defined through Devise or some other authentication system.  What your error means is the current user isn't actually logged into the system.  You need to figure out why they are not actively logged in before you start to deal with your other issue, which it appears won't be an issue once you get the proper user logged in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably you got this error because you are not logged, and current_user equals `nil`. You should check that user is logged before this action and create something `callback`. Devise offers you:

```
before_action :authenticate_user!
```

and you shoud use it in your controller like this:

```
before_action :authenticate_user!, only: [:new,:create]
```

Answer (score 0):

Fix your Devise so `current_user` is actually a thing.

Alternatively, you can grab a rails console and do the following to confirm that line.  This assumes you have a user in your database.

```
bundle exec rails c
u = User.first
u.docs.build
```

Comment: how would i make current_user a thing in devise?